# Dynamic Reports BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal, dynamic-reports

I am trying to build a report with multiple columns. I have a column `total` that represents the summation of the previous columns.

However, the value I am getting is of type `BigDecimal` and the return type of the `.add` method is `BigDecimal` and not integer, for example: 12.00 and I want it to be shown as only 12 in the report.

Here is my code:

```
TextColumnBuilder<Integer> col1 = col.column("Locked Users" , "Locked" , DataTypes.integerType());
TextColumnBuilder<Integer> col2 = col.column("Unlocked Users" , "unlocked" , DataTypes.integerType());
TextColumnBuilder<Integer> col3 = col.column("Failed Logins" , "invalid" , DataTypes.integerType());
TextColumnBuilder<Integer> col4 = col.column("Forgot Password" , "Passforget" , DataTypes.integerType());
TextColumnBuilder<BigDecimal> col5 = col1.add(col2).add(col3).add(col4).setTitle("Total");
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You can get the `int` value from a `BigDecimal` as follows, for example: `BigDecimal b  = new BigDecimal("12.00")` then get the int value with `b.intValue()`

Comment: thats in normal java , it doesnt apply on columns in dynamic reports

Comment: I don't know dynamic-reports but you could use BigInteger instead of BigDecimal. Something like this should give you format option I guess ...

Comment: Then I am afraid you may have to do some `AbstractSimpleExpression` overriding using own inner classes.

Answer (score 2):

By default Big Decimal type has following format "#,##0.00#"

You could override it for your column

```
 col5.setPattern("#,##0");
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use fraction then use the `BigInteger` instead of `BigDecimal`.
Or you can use as below,

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##"); 
df.format(yourNumber);
```